# Why don't I receive email notifications for build failures in travis

Tags: github, build, travis-ci, email-notifications

I have configured the travis.yml as shown below

```
notifications:
  email:
   recipients:
   - abc@xyz.com
   on_success: change
   on_failure: always
```

and my account is registered with github. I dont receive email notifications when one of the Jobs of travis build fails. How to solve this problem and receive email notifications whenever build fails ?

Comment: Your config looks fine - although you should indent everything under `email:` with two spaces, not one. Is there any `branch:` directive in your config? Also note that pull requests do not trigger a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Are these pull request builds?

> Pull Request builds do not trigger email notifications.

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/